# Зачем создавать новый объект класса в методе equals()

Tags: java

Почему всегда делают так: `A other = (A) obj; other.a`,
вместо обращения к переменной переданного объекта `obj.a`?

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
     {
      if (obj==null) 
       return false;

      if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass() )
       return false;

      A other = (A) obj;
      return this.a* other.b== this.b* other.a;
     }
```

Comment: Кто и где всегда так делает и с каких пор это вообще компилируется?

Comment: наверное, Вам не понравилось что был класс Object, сейчас изменил его на класс A. Только не понял почему не скомпилировалось бы?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну если поля `a` и `b` типа `Integer`, например, то вполне скомпилируется. Хотя логика сравнения все равно странная.

Comment: У вас нет создания нового объекта. `(A) obj` — это приведение типов, а не создание объекта типа `A` на основе объекта `obj`.

Comment: if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) не совсем корректное сравнение. лучше использовать instanceOf

Comment: @andreycha не нужно быть таким категоричным. приведу пример, есть родительский класс, есть классы потомки. Ваш метод будет работать только с классом родителем, что не всегда хорошо.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov ну тогда наверное стоит уточнить, что "лучше в некоторых случаях". Потому что в общем случае это весьма спорная идея. С одной стороны, использование `getClass()` ведет к нарушению LSP, с другой стороны, использование `instanceof()` ведет к нарушению равенства `x.equals(y) == y.equals(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта стандартная реализация. Интерфейс подразумевает, что в метод `equals()` может попасть любой объект.

Соответственно, нам сначала нужно выяснить, имеет ли смысл проверка: если этот объект `null` или он другого типа, то мы с ним точно не равны (`return false;`).

После того, как мы выяснили, что переданный объект нужного нам типа, можно сравнивать поля. Но нам передан параметр типа `Object`, а в нем поля `a` и `b` отсутствуют. Поэтому мы приводим его к нашему типу `A` (`A other = (A) obj;`), при этом новый объект не создается. И вот теперь мы может обращаться к полям `a` и `b`.

P.S. Правда логика сравнения у вас странная. По идее должно быть так:

```
return this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b;
```

Comment: Думаю, что у ТС объект является на самом деле рациональной дробью.

Comment: @VladD тогда будут проблемы с `getHashCode()`.

Comment: @VladD Да и с умножением могут быть проблемы если числа близки к максимальным значениям.

Comment: Угу, но ТС покамест не понимает, почему у `Object` нельзя получить доступ к полям `a` и `b` (то есть не понимает разницу между заявленным и фактическим типами), а вы про высокие материи.

Comment: @VladD ну про высокие материи мы ж между собой общаемся :).

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял.